# Remove all sub directories with rimraf on node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a directory structure where certain folder Data has sub directories. At some point I want those removed all at once and I've installed the otherwise awesome [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) package for node.js

My code so far:

```
var dataPath === Path.normalize(__dirname + '/backend/data/');

rimraf(dataPath, function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

I've tried with both ***/backend/data/*** and ***/backend/data/* ***, but none seems to do the trick - the first deletes the entire *data* folder and the second fires an error *'Can't delete null'*

I guess I could scan the main directory, find all sub folders and delete them one by one, but if this can be done with `rimraf` or a similar package, I'd rather go with it.

Comment: I've been working with rimraf recently and have had success with your second option using glob. Perhaps the latest version of rimraf now handles the wild card better? Definitely worth you revisiting this as I'm using almost identical code to you and it leaves the data folder intact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just re-create the `data` directory after `rimraf` finishes deleting it. Depending on your use case, that can introduce a race condition, but I doubt `rimraf` itself is race-safe in any situations where that isn't.

Another option is to read the contents of the directory and `rimraf` each of those, but that is more work and doesn't avoid any race conditions that would affect the first option.

Comment: I ended up with this solution in the end: I fist create a temporary directory `data-temp` and fill it with all necessary data, and upon success delete the `data` directory and rename the `data-temp` back to `data`. Kinda lame solution, but it works and is quick and until some more suitable package comes up I'll keep it.

Comment: is rimraf async?

Answer (score 4):

The current version of rimraf supports globs, so one could just add an asterisk to the end of the folder, like so:

```
rimraf( path.join(__dirname, "./uploads/*"), (err) => { ... });
```